# SVG blur filter creates strange artifacts in desktop Safari only

Tags: svg, safari, svg-filters

I'm trying to work with SVG blur filter and get these strange artifacts in desktop Safari (Version 8.0.2 (10600.2.5)). To reproduce this bug please visit demo link below.

Blur code is pretty simple:

```
<filter id='bf1'>
    <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation='0 50' />
</filter>
```

[**DEMO** (bug presents in desktop Safari only)](http://codepen.io/bobelev/full/yyavwL/)
**[Source code](http://codepen.io/bobelev/pen/yyavwL)**

[image]

If scroll down a bit artifact stays still.

[image]

In Chrome and Firefox everthing works just fine.

[image]

Help me please to get rid of this transparency bars.

**EDITED:**

I found that Safari splits image into 512x512 squares.
[Demo](http://codepen.io/bobelev/full/pvEOda/)
[Source code](http://codepen.io/bobelev/pen/pvEOda)

[image]

Comment: Is this mobile safari or desktop safari? Can you please post full code so people can try to reproduce?

Comment: @MichaelMullany I've posted links to code and added browser description.